# Using a variable inside the string for SQL queries using python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, algorithm

i want to see all the data of a particular table of sql database `world` entered by user, The below code will give me desired output for `city` table, but i want table name to be entered by user and wants to make my code work for all the cases.

```
from sqlite3 import connect
import mysql.connector 
mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",database='world')
mycursor=mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("select * from city")
for i in mycursor:
    print(i)
```

**I thought to declare `city` as string variable**

```
table_name=str(input("enter table name:"))
mycursor=mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("select * from table_name")
for i in mycursor:
    print(i)
```

**But i'm getting an error world.table_name doesn't exist, which i understand. is there any way to evolve at solution of my case. looking for kind help, thanks a lot.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use concatenation

```
table_name=str(input("enter table name:"))
query = "SELECT * FROM " + table_name
mycursor.execute(query)
```

Comment: [Someone had to add this.](https://xkcd.com/327/). Use prepared statements.

Comment: Or at least, quote the table name with backticks: `q = 'select * from \`%s\` % table_name` to reduce the risk of SQL injection (checking that the table name is an actual table would also be wise).